# pandas is not summing a numeric column

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have read into a DataFrame an Excel spreadsheet with column names such as Gross, **Fee**, Net, etc. When I invoke the `sum` method on the resulting DataFrame, I saw that it was not summing the **Fee** column because several rows had string data in that column. So I first loop through each row testing that column to see if it contains a string and if it does, I replace it with a 0. The DataFrame `sum` method still does not sum the **Fee** column. Yet when I write out the resulting DataFrame to a new Excel spreadsheet and read it back in and apply the `sum` method to the resulting DataFrame, it does sum the **Fee** column. Can anyone explain this? Here is the code and the printed output:

```
import pandas as pd

pp = pd.read_excel('pp.xlsx')
# get rid of any strings in column 'Fee':
for i in range(pp.shape[0]):
    if isinstance(pp.loc[i, 'Fee'], str):
        pp.loc[i, 'Fee'] = 0
pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee']) #added this but it makes no difference
# the Fee column is still not summed:
print(pp.sum(numeric_only=True))

print('\nSecond Spreadsheet\n')

# write out Dataframe: to an Excel spreadheet:
with pd.ExcelWriter('pp2.xlsx') as writer:
    pp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PP')
# now read the spreadsheet back into another DataFrame:
pp2 = pd.read_excel('pp2.xlsx')
# the Fee column is summed:
print(pp2.sum(numeric_only=True))
```

Prints:

```
Gross                                                          8677.90
Net                                                            8572.43
Address Status                                                    0.00
Shipping and Handling Amount                                      0.00
Insurance Amount                                                  0.00
Sales Tax                                                         0.00
etc.

Second Spreadsheet

Unnamed: 0                                                     277885.00
Gross                                                            8677.90
Fee                                                              -105.47
Net                                                              8572.43
Address Status                                                      0.00
Shipping and Handling Amount                                        0.00
Insurance Amount                                                    0.00
Sales Tax                                                           0.00
etc.
```

Comment: could you do a `pp['Fee'].dtype` before doing the `pp.sum(numeric_only=True)` the first time?

Comment: pp['Fee'].dtype -> object

Comment: Does my answer make sense to you? Pandas should inherently convert the column to `float64` but I don't know why it doesn't do it in this case.

Comment: Existing issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20635

Comment: @Danny The "accepted" answer also converts the the column to float64 whereas just `to_numeric(pp['Fee'])` did not seem to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Fee column isn't numeric. So you need to convert it to a numeric field, save that updated field in the existing dataframe, and then compute the sum.

So that would be:

```py
df = df.assign(Fee=pd.to_numeric(df['Fee'], errors='coerce'))
print(df.sum())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pd.to_numeric`

**Ex:**

```
pp = pd.read_excel('pp.xlsx')
print(pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'], errors='coerce').dropna().sum())
```

Comment: By the way, I can get a sum with pp['Fee'].sum(): -105.47000000000001.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'], errors='coerce').dropna().sum()` yields -105.47, but `pp.sum()` still does not print the Fee column, which is my original issue.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick analysis, from what I can see is that you are replacing the string with an integer and the values of `'Fee'` column could be a mix of both of float and integer which means the `dtype` of that column is an `object`. When you do `pp.sum(numeric_only=True)` , it ignores the object column because of the condition `numeric_only`. Convert your column to a `float64` as in `pp['Fee'] = pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'])` and it should work for you.

The reason that it is happening second time is because excel does the data conversion for you and when you read it, it's a `numeric` data type.

Comment: `could be a mix of both of float and integer which means the dtype of that column is an object` this is wrong, the dtype would be "float"

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})`              `df1.loc[2,'B'] = 'a'`
`df1.loc[3,'B'] = 0.00`      `df1['B'].dtype`            `for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    if isinstance(df1.loc[i, 'B'], str):
        df1.loc[i, 'B'] = 0.00`   `df1['B'].dtype`   This should tell you the story. I am sorry for the indentation here.

Comment: @PaulH You can look at the comment under the question.

Comment: I added `pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'])`, but it made no difference. By the way, I can get a sum with `pp['Fee'].sum()`: -105.47000000000001.

Comment: @Danny it's an object column because of the *strings*, not b/c of mixed ints and floats

Comment: but look at my code in the second comment. When you convert a value in a column from `str` to `float` it doesn't change the column type to `float64` it still remains as an `object`

Comment: I also should have mentioned that assigning a value of 0 or 0.00 makes no difference.

Comment: changing the value of a `str` to a `float` does not change the column type to `float64` but when you change from `str` to `int`, it does change to `int64`. I am guessing that's expected?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Could you try `pp['Fee'] = pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'], downcast='float')`?

Comment: I just posted this as the correct answer having realized that you have to assign the converted column back to the original DataFrame. Update your actual answer with this (you don't need the downcast). And I will accept this.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson any reason why the other answer was picked? Performance? Quicker? No offence here but just wanted to know.

Comment: Because it was not first necessary to first loop through all the elements of the column and replace those elements which were strings with 0.00.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was not aware of the `coerce` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who has responded should get partial credit for telling me about pd.to_numeric. But they were all missing one piece. It is not sufficient to say `pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee']`. That returns the column converted to numeric but does *not* update the original DataFrame, so when I do a `pp.sum()`, nothing in `pp` was modified. You need:

```
pp['Fee'] = pd.to_numeric(pp['Fee'])
pp.sum()
```